# What is wrong with Outlook 2010 and Gmail IMAP?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail-imap

I have set up my Gmail account with Outlook 2010 SP1 using IMAP. One problem is bugging me like anything here is the sync problem. When I hit "Mark All as Read" in outlook for gmail account, outlook becomes non-responsive for several minutes. On the other hand Windows Live Mail is setup with same gmail account in same machine, but it is quite fast in this operation.

I let outlook automatically set up my gmail account, but I don't know what's going wrong here.

Following is my system spec

```
Win7 ultimate 32 sp1
Outlook 2010 sp1
MS Security essential
Comodo firewall [IMAP ports are open, as WLM is working fine]
```

Can anybody please suggest me some workaround here to speed outlook up? I have searched a lot in Google and MS Office help site, but nothing is of good help.

Comment: How many messages are you syncing to your Outlook? Every single message from Gmail, or only the last couple of days or so?

Comment: I have over 2000 mails in Gmail, but all them except the recent 20 mails are all READ. I am trying to mark those 20 messages as READ from outlook. Same operation is happening in WLM in just moments, but outlook seems to take forever!!!

Comment: I usually use this option for Spam and Trash folders-"Download holders only" and for Inbox and Drafts-"Download complete item including attachments".This prevents Outlook from downloading mails and attachments that are marked as Spam by Gmail.

Comment: I too had the same problem but [this](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/solutions-for-slow-gmail-imap-with-microsoft-outlook/1761/) helped me out.